# Getting bad response on route calculation when using departure or large stopover

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

When doing this request:

https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=[my-app_id]&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:enabled;&currency=EUR&restTimes=EU&traverseGates=true&tollVehicleType=3&legAttributes=none,li,-mn&rollups=none,country&departure=2019-10-24T12:00:00&waypoint0=stopOver,3600!geo!40.6457299,-7.8720095&waypoint1=stopOver,3600!geo!40.538969,-7.855085&waypoint2=stopOver,3600!geo!40.3636881,-8.0241749&waypoint3=stopOver,3600!geo!38.7222524,-9.1393366&waypoint4=geo!37.0193548,-7.9304397

I get the error message :

```
{
  "issues": [
    {
      "message": "Couldn't reach way point 4 due to search timeout (start links -537276209 -746448836 1213280170 -537276209 -746448836 1213280170 -537276209 -537276209 1213280170 -746448836 -746448836 -746448836 1213280170 -537276209 1213280170 -537276209 -746448836 -746448836 1213280170 -537276209 -537276209 1213280170 -537276209 1213280170 -746448836 -537276209 1213280170 -746448836 -746448836 -537276209 1213280170 -746448836 1213280170 -537276209  dest links 545917165 -545917165 )"
    },
    {
      "message": "Request id: bca15488-a510-41d7-a1e0-90c60d045bc5"
    }
  ],
  "response": null,
  "error_id": "bca15488-a510-41d7-a1e0-90c60d045bc5",
  "response_code": "400 Bad Request"
}
```

However if I either remove the departure field or put a lower stopover, it works, but i needed both fields with those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of waypoints is limited. However, this limit is not a fixed number but is a result of the limit for the overall processing time. By the time search reaches to 4th waypoint, the execution time ends for the API. This is what is configured for this API search time out limit.

However it works fine by reducing one stop over. You can either combine the two results. Will raise it to the developer to check if the execution time limit can be extended or not.